# Reactjs checkboxes not working in the update state of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a component called `User.js`. There I have a section for pick user permissions.

[image]

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} container>
    <FormControl>
    <FormLabel>Permissions</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup row>
      {routes.map((route) =>
        route.children.map((e,i) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={2}>
            <FormControlLabel
            
              control={<Checkbox name="permissions"
              value= {e.path}  
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}/>}                                  
              label={route.name + " " + e.name}
              key={i}
            />
          </Grid>
        ))
      )}
    </FormGroup>

    </FormControl>
</Grid>
```

This is the full code for that permissions section. This works correctly when I create a new user. Permissions pass to the back-end like this `permissions: ['/create-user','update-user'],`

When I try to update a user, using the same component. Checkboxes are not ticked. Even though the `permissions` array filled with these values `permissions: ['/create-user','update-user'],`

I use formik for validations and my entire `Grid` is wrapped with

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={submit}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  enableReinitialize
>
```

since I pass `enableReinitialize` prop I don't think that formik block the rendering.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FormControlLabel of material-ui, then in control prop the checkbox will need 'checked' prop which will have boolean value.

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Checkbox
      name="permissions"
      value={e.path}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      checked={/*permission array contains path*/}
    />
  }
  label={route.name + " " + e.name}
  key={i}
/>;
```